# How to pass multiple strings to command line argument in another application in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have to trigger another application after user done with my GUI. In order to trigger another application, i have to pass some command line argument to start that application. Let's say I have to pass below arguments:

*c:\Program File\application.exe
-name text
-cmdfile c:\text\open.txt*

The application.exe is a parameter that i want to pass to another applcation.

Before, that application set those argument in **Visual Studio** -> **Properties** -> **Debug** as "*c:\Program File\application.exe" -name text -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt*

As i understand, every space in above string consider as an argument except the one inside double quotes, so *"c:\Program File\application.exe"* is the first argument, *-name* is the second and *text* is the third. However, if i am using **ProcessStartInfo.Argument** property, if I set *"c:\Program File\application.exe" -name text -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt*, it first of all give an error, and than I add double quotes at the end of string, another application consider *c:\Program* as first argument and *File\application.exe* as second argument.

How can I avoid space as the separator for arguments? How can I pass the whole string as the same format setup in Visual **Studio** -> **Properties** -> **Debug** as "*c:\Program File\application.exe" -name text -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt* using **ProcessStartInfo.Argument** property?

> ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
>   startInfo.Arguments = "c:\Program File\application.exe" -name text
>   -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt

(error)

if

> startInfo.Arguments = "c:\Program File\application.exe -name text
>   -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt"

it takes *c:\Program* as first argument and *File\application.exe* as second argument.

How can I figure this out? Any experience on that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As a rule, we won't write your code for you so, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try to add '@' before the string. This should help

Comment: Are you starting the other app using the `Process` class?

Comment: Use `@"My String Contents\Path` to make C# clear that you it has to interprete as verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to start `application.exe`, or are you passing that as a parameter?

If you are starting it you can use:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program File\application.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = @"-name text -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If you are trying to start another process and want to pass `application.exe` as a parameter with the other parameters you could try:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("application2.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = @"""c:\Program File\application.exe"" -name text -cmdfile c:\text\open.txt";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I want to passing that as a parameter.That application will trigger application.exe. So I will try the second one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used second way to try it, is still consider File\application.exe as second parameter. How can i let argument understand c:\Program File\application.exe should be the first one?

Comment: Found an online compiler that let me get the `"`s right. Edit should work now.